# How to proxy all XMLHttpRequest requests in a web application?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I am trying to proxy all `XMLHttpRequest` requests my web application is making through a proxy server. I am able to do this for all `fetch` requests rather easily via a service worker:

```
// sw-proxy.js
// I've trimmed out the business logic in this function - but you can see that I can easily proxy my request onwards.
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
    // ... some business logic
    e.respondWith(fetch('https://my-proxy-server.com'));
});
```

However, it looks like `XMLHttpRequest` isn't available in the service worker context (I'm not 100% certain about this but it looks like it from the [spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/), [this Github issue](https://github.com/whatwg/xhr/issues/19) and from what code I've tried). This basically leaves me with the option of monkey patching `XMLHttpRequest` - which definitely doesn't *feel* ideal.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this, other than monkey patching?

Comment: Even if this worked, wouldn't it make all your endpoints identical? If this is for development, I'd use the proxy in package.json: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/ The page also discusses using "http-proxy-middleware" from npm, which might be a better solution for you.

Comment: I trivialised my code implementation a little too much. It is possible to pass on the original request to the proxy layer so it knows where to forward the request onto. This isn't just for development - unfortunately I can't use that package you suggested because this has to be done in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the code provided in the question is the answer. The `fetch` event that is being listened to isn't just from the Fetch API; it will also intercept XHR requests too.